# conditional formatting in MS Project

Tags: microsoft-project

I need to use conditional formatting to change the colour of the font to white in the 'Cost' field if the figures is between 0-500. 
I only want to format the "Cost" field and not the entire row

I would be greateful if someone genius can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done natively, but can be achieved with some VBA code. I've copied a sample i prepared previously which applies formatting to the flag1 column based on its value. A bit of tweaking should get it doing what you need. You'll need to run the code to refresh - it won't recalculate after each edit.

I hope that helps,
Andrew

```
    Sub ApplyFormattingToFlag1()
' ===================================================================================
' ===== This section applies the formatting to the current view                 =====
' ===================================================================================
Dim t As task
Dim pj As Project
Dim boo_AnyYes
Dim app As Application
Set app = MSProject.Application
Set pj = activeProject
boo_AnyYes = False
    For Each t In pj.Tasks

        If t.Flag1 = True Then
            boo_AnyYes = True
        End If

    Next t


    With app
        .ScreenUpdating = False ' Attempt to stop the screen refreshing

        .FilterApply "&All Tasks"
        .OutlineHideSubTasks
        .OutlineShowAllTasks

        .SelectTaskColumn Column:="flag1"

        If boo_AnyYes Then
            .FontEx CellColor:=1, Pattern:=1
        Else
            .FontEx CellColor:=16, Pattern:=0
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```